# Does a sub-theme needs the main theme enable?

Tags: theming

Just to clarified a doubt. 
But when creating a sub-theme, is it necessary to have the main theme enable ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

No, it is not necessary. You need to have your base theme installed, but you don't need to enable it: https://www.drupal.org/node/225125#comment-7716513

**EDIT**: Note that if you want to access the settings for your base theme, you will need to enable it, as noted by @MPD in a comment below.

Comment: It can cause weirdness if you need to access base theme settings, since you won't be able to.

Comment: @MPD, you are completely right! I have just edited my answer.